# What is the difference between Eclipse RCP and EMF Client Platform (ECP)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I couldn't find any hints what the difference between Eclipse RCP and EMF Client Platform (ECP). Can anybody explain the difference please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RCP stands for Rich Client Platform.  You need to provide a link for the Eclipse Client Platform.

Comment: Sorry. It was meant to be EMF Client Platform. Does EMF Client Platform bases on RCP? I didn't really get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Eclipse EMF Client Platform web page](http://eclipse.org/ecp/index.html):

> The EMF Client Platform is a framework for building EMF-based client applications. The goal is to provide reusable, adaptable and extensible UI components to develop applications based on a given EMF model. All components can be used stand-alone and be embedded into your own application.

The Eclipse Rich Client Platform allows you to construct a general GUI using the GUI components of Eclipse.

The Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) Client Platform allows you to build form based business GUI's and create custom EMF components for form based business GUI's.

I've created RCP applications.  I've not used the EMF Client Platform.

Comment: So does it mean that the EMF Client Platform provides in-box solution for an application for visualizing model elements? And for an RCP application you begin at 0 and combine plugins to create your own gui-based application.

Comment: @Moonstar: Sort of.  EMF is designed for label, textfield, label, textfield, etc.